# Why do we use a sub-queries in SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery

I don't understand we would need to use sub-queries in data analysis or why the order matters. Can someone explain it to me?

Example: Why do the 2 codes below produce 2 different outputs from the difference in ordering of the code? They are both trying to find the lowest rental price in 2006.

Code 1:

```
SELECT
     film_id
    ,title
FROM Films
WHERE release_year = 2006 
AND rental_rate =
(
    SELECT
        MIN(rental_rate)
    FROM Films
);
```

Code 2:

```
SELECT 
     film_id
    ,title
FROM Films
WHERE rental_rate = 
(
    SELECT
        MIN(rental_rate)
    FROM Films
    WHERE release_year = 2006
);
```

Comment: The first query returns films from 2006 with a rental_rate equal to the lowest rental_rate ever (so including all other years). The second query returns films from all years with a rental_rate that was equal to the lowest rental_rate in 2006.

Comment: Say lowest rental price in 2006 was $5, and lowest rental price in 2002 was $3.

Comment: It would help to know what alternative you're considering that tries to solve your (under-)stated requirement and doesn't use a subquery. If it's to first find the lowest rental rate of 2006 in one query and then to use that found value in a second query then it helps to know that in SQL, you aim to tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*, and part of that is letting the optimizer work out which tasks to do when, or in parallel, etc.